# AngularFire2 OAuth2 with Google getting Firebase Authorization error

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to use Google Authentication to get written permission to my Firebase data.  However, while I believe I have most things configured, it is not working when I attempt to connect to Google, and I am not sure what to set next.

Login function on my page:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public AFAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }
...
login() {

    this.AFAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then(function(result) {
            this.GoogleAccessToken = result.credential.accessToken;     // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            this.GoogleUser = result.user;                          // The signed-in user info.
            this.LoggedIn = true;
            console.log('Logged In');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error Logging In: ' + error)
        }
    );
}
```

I am always getting this error:

```
Error Logging In: Error: This app, identified by the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key configuration in the Google API console.
```

Note the my data is set to Read only, and my application accesses all the data correctly, so I have the AngularFire Firebase connection strings correct.

I have also validated that the Firebase.apiKey and Firebase.authDomain both match the settings in the Google API Manager.  My authDomain is also white listed on the `Browser key (auto created by Google Service)` as an `HTTP referrers (web sites)`.

I have tried this from my localhost with port being whitelisted (development machine) and by placing the code on the website to test it, and it also fails.

All the references are http://xxxxx.domain.com, without the www as we do not access our application from www.domain.com.

To remove the reference settings as a possible issue, I have changed the reference filter to None.  However, this then results in an `Error 401, deleted_client.  The OAth client was deleted.`

Answer (score 1):

You must have some referrer restrictions on your browser API key.
In the Google Cloud Console, go to the browser key that you are using, typically it is labeled (auto created by Google service) and set "Key restriction" to "None".

Comment: Even moving back to None, so there is no restriction, then I get a `Error 401, deleted_client.  The OAth client was deleted.`  I have added this to my original question to help clarify.